# Android Databinding - How to set contentDescription and src for ImageView

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to set a `contentDescription` this way:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/accountType"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:contentDescription="@{() -> account.getContentDescription()}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

My account class:

```
data class Account(
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val title: String,
    val accountType: AccountType,
    val balance: Double = 0.0
) {
fun getAccountTypeDrawable() =
        when (accountType) {
            AccountType.CHECKING_ACCOUNT -> R.drawable.ic_account_balance_black_48dp
            AccountType.WALLET -> R.drawable.ic_local_atm_black_48dp
            AccountType.SAVINGS_ACCOUNT -> R.drawable.ic_package_black_48dp
            AccountType.INVESTMENT -> R.drawable.ic_trending_up_black_48dp
            AccountType.OTHER -> R.drawable.ic_lens_black_48dp
        }

fun getContentDescription(view: View) =
        view.context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.account_type)[accountType.ordinal]!!
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the proper callback class for android:contentDescription. Tried java.lang.CharSequence but it has 4 abstract methods, should have 1 abstract methods.
>   file:C:\Users\Douglas\AndroidStudioProjects\Currency\app\src\main\res\layout\item_account.xml
>   loc:23:42 - 23:78
>   ****\ data binding error ****

If I set directly in xml like this it works as expected:

```
android:contentDescription="@{context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.account_type)[account.accountType.ordinal]}"
```

But I created the method inside Account class to avoid doing this all the time.

How can I set `contentDescription` and `app:srcCompat` for the `ImageView` using the methods in Account class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use context directly:

```
android:contentDescription="@{account.getContentDescription(context)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass direclty the name of the view (is the id as Android Data Binding camel-cases).
In your case you can use:

```
android:contentDescription="@{account.getContentDescription(accountType)}"
app:srcCompat="@{account.getAccountTypeDrawable()}"
```